# How to find the percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `streaming` with the columns `service` and `genre`. I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM streaming 
WHERE genre LIKE '%kids%' 
   OR genre LIKE '&family&'
   OR genre LIKE '%children%';
```

When I run the above query, it returns 171 rows.

```
SELECT 
    service, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN genre LIKE '%kids%' 
                 OR genre LIKE '&family&'
                 OR genre LIKE '%children%'
              THEN 1.0000 
              OR 0.0000
              END ) AS perc_family                        
FROM streaming
GROUP BY service
ORDER BY perc_family;
```

This statement returns:

| service | perc_family |
| --- | --- |
| disney | 4 |
| hulu | 18 |
| amazon | 42 |
| netflix | 107 |

But I want to find the percentage of content geared towards children by each platform:

| service | perc_family |
| --- | --- |
| disney | 2.3 |
| hulu | 10.5 |
| amazon | 24.6 |
| netflix | 62.6 |

Comment: `1.0000 or 0.0000` -- Are you sure you wanted to type that?

Comment: Well, if you divide all numbers by 171 you have the percentag i assume.
Is it that what you want?

Comment: @h.m.i.13 yes. I wanted to do that

Comment: Is the '&family&' intentional or is it a typo and you ment '%family%'?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not the best solution, but I think it works:

```
SELECT sums.service, sums.perc_family * 100 / total.s AS `percent of total`
FROM (SELECT service, 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN genre like '%kids%' 
                       OR genre like '%family%'
                       OR genre like '%children%' then 1 or 0 end) AS perc_family
FROM streaming 
GROUP BY service) AS sums
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS s 
             FROM streaming 
             WHERE genre LIKE '%kids%' 
             OR    genre LIKE '%family%'
             OR    genre LIKE '%children%') total;
```

an easyer to read solution is:

```
SELECT service, COUNT(CASE WHEN genre like '%kids%' 
                       OR genre like '%family%'
                       OR genre like '%children%' then 1 or 0 end) * 100 / 
                        (SELECT count(*) 
                         FROM streaming 
                         WHERE genre LIKE '%kids%' 
                         OR    genre LIKE '%family%'
                         OR    genre LIKE '%children%') AS `percent of total`
FROM streaming 
GROUP BY service
```

I used this [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gTZN4dcTX1qDLw58z31zhe/4)

What have I done? First I corrected the "&" and then I divide the absolut value throug the sum. For this I use a subquery to get the total sum. That doesn't work in the same query, because it is grouped according to the individual services.