# Creating Percentage using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, percentage

I am trying to create a percentage from two different tables. My two tables, Orders.(OrderID,SKU) and RMA.(RMAID,OrderID). I want to have SKU's and their percentage of returns in comparison to the total number of returns.

```sql
SELECT SKU, COUNT(RMA.RMAID)/(COUNT(DISTINCT SKU)) AS TOTAL_RETURNS
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN RMA ON Orders.Order1D=RMA.Order1D
GROUP BY SKU
ORDER BY TOTAL_RETURNS DESC;
```

This gets me the total returns, but how do I get it in percentage form?

Comment: Select the two values (`COUNT(RMA.RMAID)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT SKU)`) separately, and check if they have values which meet expectations.

Comment: possibly this https://stackoverflow.com/q/74239393/3604523 could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    SKU, 
    (100 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() ) AS RMA_SKU_PERCENT
FROM RMA
JOIN Orders
ON RMA.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
GROUP BY SKU
ORDER BY RMA_SKU_PERCENT;
```

Take out the `100 *` if you want the percentage as a decimal fraction (between 0 and 1) -- otherwise it returns a percentage number (between 0 and 100).